# $geoWithin $box bug?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, geospatial

I have the following document in my MongoDB database:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "55002a7916157e6021de5708"
    },
    "city": "Wellington New Zealand",
    "location": [
        174.77623600000004,
        -41.2864603
    ]
}
```

When I try to find it out by the following geospatial query I don't get it:

```
db.collection.find({
    "location": {
        "$geoWithin": {
            "$box": [
                [165.8694369, -52.61941849999999],
                [-175.831536, -29.2313419]
            ]
        }
    }
});
```

Could you explain why the query above does not work?

Comment: Have you tried changing the order of your arguments in the $box operator? Could MongoDB be interpreting your latitude/longitude oppositely to the way you are? This is something that has tricked me in the past.

Comment: yes, I've tried but it doesn't work :(

Comment: What version of MongoDB are you using?

Comment: I'm using the latest 3.0

Comment: It's realy bug because from this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29168008/googlemaps-geocoder-results-wrong-bounds-of-new-zealand @geocodezip provided the example of bounds in google Maps http://jsfiddle.net/eg9txvgp/1/

Comment: The blue rectangle is the box from this post. It seems MongoDB does't handles it.

Answer (score 6):

Those coordinates are not valid since the longitude of the "upper right" is reversed from what it should be:

```js
db.collection.find({
    "location": {
        "$geoWithin": {
            "$box": [
                [165.8694369, -52.61941849999999],
                [175.831536, -29.2313419]
            ]
        }
    }
})
```

That returns the desired location correctly. I recommend you use something like http://geojsonlint.com/ when testing features.

Your "box" looks like this:

[image]

Which of course covers all of the earth between the latitudes "except" the desired area. So that is why it fails.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'm getting these bounds from GoogleMaps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29168008/googlemaps-geocoder-results-wrong-bounds-of-new-zealand Is it possible to somehow to detect and fix bounds before querying in DB?

Comment: @Erik What I have stated are the "correct bounds" for your query and also made a point of completely explaining why your bounds are "incorrect". From the start of your questioning, I wanted you to understand why you assumptions are not correct and that you "should" use "metadata" such as  `( "country" : "New Zealand" }` in your storage as opposed to looking for a bounding `$box` or `"Polygon"` per GeoJSON as expected. Please see the correct way to model this.